# Which version of webMathematica should I use for mathematica 10.3?

Tags: version-10, webmathematica

Where can I find which version of webMathematica is compatible with which version of mathematica? The only hint I've found is this page: http://support.wolfram.com/kb/22167 but it's focused on end-of-support date, I don't known if it implies a strict relation between webMathematica and mathematica versions in the table.

```
╔════════════════╦══════════════════╦══════════════════════════╗
║ webMathematica ║ Wolfram Language ║ End-of-Developer-Support ║
╠════════════════╬══════════════════╬══════════════════════════╣
║          3.3.1 ║             10.1 ║ 03/31/2018               ║
║          3.3.2 ║             10.2 ║ 09/30/2018               ║
║          3.3.3 ║             10.3 ║ 12/31/2018               ║
║          3.3.4 ║             10.4 ║ 06/30/2019               ║
║          3.4.0 ║             11.0 ║ 03/31/2020               ║
║          3.4.1 ║             11.1 ║ 06/30/2020               ║
║          3.4.2 ║             11.2 ║ 09/30/2020               ║
╚════════════════╩══════════════════╩══════════════════════════╝
```